# how does BatchNorm1d() method whithin the torch library work?

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

I'm learning pytorch, I don;t know if this question is stupid but I can't find the official web for explaining nn.batchnorm1d. I'm wondering how `torch.nn.BatchNorm1d(d1)` work? I know that batch norm is about making mean and variance of a batch of example to be 0 and 1 respectively. I'm wondering if there is nn.batchnorm2d, if so, what does it do? what is the `d1` parameter ?

Answer (score 7):

`BatchNorm1d` normalises data to 0 mean and unit variance for 2/3-dimensional data `(N, C)` or `(N, C, L)`, computed over the channel dimension at each `(N, L)` or `(N,)` slice; while `BatchNorm2d` does the same thing for 4 dimensions `(N, C, H, W)`, computed over the channel dimension at each `(N, H, W)` slice.

Which one to use depends on the dimensionality of input data. For instance in image processing, feature maps ususally have 2 spatial dimensions `(N, C, H, W)`, so [`BatchNorm2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/batchnorm.html#BatchNorm2d) is useful here. However for some NLP tasks, if there is only the length dimension to consider, one would use [`BatchNorm1d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/batchnorm.html#BatchNorm1d). For both functions, the `d1` parameter is the number of features, and equals dim `C` of the input tensor.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the official documentation for PyTorch's BatchNorm:

[BatchNorm1D](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#batchnorm1d) and [BatchNorm2D](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#batchnorm2d)

As per the documentation we need to specify `num_features` parameter which is the input size of tensor.

Comment: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BatchNorm1d.html#torch.nn.BatchNorm1d Consider this link for batchnorm1D. & https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BatchNorm2d.html for batchnorm 2D